# Transform a Column into dictionary and access

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df.source)

                    source
0     "{'id': None, 'name': 'Cnet.com'}",
1     "{'id': None, 'name': 'Cnet.com'}",
2     "{'id': None, 'name': 'Cnet.com'}",

...
```

And I would like to access the information contained in "name", ultimately creating:

```
print(df_final.source)

                    source
0                  Cnet.com
1                  Cnet.com
2                  Cnet.com

...
```

I tried with:

```
dictio = df["source"].to_dict()

for i in range(0, len(df)):

     dictio[i]["name"]
```

but it raises the error: "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

How can I create df_final?

Comment: You'd have to do `df['source'] = df['source'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])` This assumes you have a dict in all rows, and that the key `'name'` exists in all dicts

Comment: It raises: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable", if I transform the column into dictionary before passing it; otherwise it raises: TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: If you use `.apply(lambda x: x.get("name", default))` you can supply  a default value `default`, that gets returned in case "name" is not present in the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to dictionaries by `ast` and then get values by `get`:

```
import ast

df['source'] = df['source'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x).get("name", 'missing value'))
```

Or if necessary working with dictionary column later:

```
import ast

df['source'] = df['source'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['source'] = df['source'].apply(lambda x: x.get("name", 'missing value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your data inside source column is in string format.
we can try this using the `json` package to convert the string to a dictionary format and then access name field from it.

i think this snippet should work.

```
import json
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sourceDict = json.loads(row['source'])
    name = sourceDict['name']
```